# Sharepoint 2010. All webparts are missing for visitor user

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

On my site all webparts is missing for visitor user.
I added visitor user for my site but when i trying to access my site with this user all custom and default sharepoint webparths are missing!

In html there is no code for webparts so this is not "visible" problem.

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't configure them as personal (i.e. available to you only)? Btw. this question is a better fit for sharepoint.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I didn't change any configuration. how to check configuration? And also if i add user to group "designer" all webparts become visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be due to security on the webparts. That the new user is not a member of a group that is required to view the web parts.

Comment: How to check that> User just a visitor. What required for sharepoint to show that webparts?